# 3-tier file upload architecture (Browser/ PHP/ API)

Tags: php, file-upload, jersey

We're currently facing a design challenge about dealing with large (>30 MB) file uploads. Our system is currently as follows:

```
Browser <---AJAX---> PHP <---OAUTH---> REST API
```

PHP and API are on different servers/domains.

Uploading a file from browser to PHP and then from PHP to API sounds like a waste of bandwidth to me.

So the idea we had in mind is to use the following sequence:

1. PHP request upload-URL from the API
2. API creates nonce and sends it back as upload-URL
3. Browser uploads the file directly to the API using the upload-URL.

So we only transfer the file data once.

Would there be anything wrong with this?

Thanks,

pepijn

Comment: and how browser will send PUT\DELETE request?

Comment: It can use POST isn't it? The browser should just POST the file to the endpoint.

Comment: Is your backend public or does it need some kind of authentication?

Comment: of course, you can use it. but read about REST API basics.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with referring to an external resource right? Isn't it similar as referring to URL's of images returned upon a REST GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PHP needs no further processing to do with the file, then it should be fine.